# lightning:inputField is not retrieving picklist values

Tags: aura

I cannot visualize all the picklist values from a lightning:inputField tag (There should be 5 items displayed)

[image]

I cannot understand why this does not work as I copied and pasted the same code in a different sandbox and It perfectly displayed the 5 picklist values. Also I created a new picklist field and it displays the data correctly.

I checked everything I could think of and nothing... This is the code for the aura component.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride">
<lightning:card title="Nuevo caso" iconName="action:new_case">
    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Case">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>
                    <lightning:inputField variant="label-stacked" fieldName="Area__c"></lightning:inputField>
                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</lightning:card>
```

</aura:component>

Comment: Can you check the respective org have all the picklist values are exist or not?

Comment: Can you check default record type related picklist values for this field

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this error. This has nothing to do with any configuration such as RecordTypes, FieldPermissions, etc.

The fields were migrated using change sets, for some odd reason the aura tag does not read the picklist values if they are coming from them.

The solution was to delete all the fields (also from the bin) and then migrate them using Visual studio code (I retrieved the metadata from the org).

After deploying from VS The fields and dependencies worked just fine.

I double checked and repeated the process using change sets and suprise surprise, the same problem again.

I am very convinced this is an bug for the lightning:inputField tag.